# How to resolve dependencies with aspnet vnext on a mac?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In trying to build NuGet3, I'm getting the following error:

```
~/Projects/NuGet3-dev/src/NuGet.CommandLine/project.json(22,46): error: The dependency fx/Microsoft.Build.Framework >= 14.0.0 could not be resolved.
```

I have no idea why it wouldn't be resolved, since according to

```
 gacutil -l
```

I have it:

```
 Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

I looked at everything I could find about this issue, but it's almost entirely Visual Studio and Windows based resolutions, and nothing seems to apply to my situation...

How to make this resolve?

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you are working on https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.CommandLine ...)

How to resolve?

Use Windows. This project is not designed to be built on Mono. It is integrated with Windows tooling.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as there is a build shell script available for FreeBSD, and the binary nuget.exe itself runs and does allow for packages to run on my machine (some via .net core, not mono) - I just don't understand why gacutil shows me that I have the correct thing, but the build can't find the reference.

Comment: gacutil is a Mono utility. Building against Mono vs running on Mono are very different things.

Answer (score 0):

Under POSIX systems (thought, some true operating system):

In short, the dependency is resolved using DNX or dotnet (said M$ .Net Core), and its `restore` command.

The `fx/` stands for framework, just drop the prefix, it should be the same. I sow these kind of notations disappear, when passing to DNX. Just try and install it using the DNX process.

since MSBuild targets and props for DNX are not available, the `xbuild` script from Mono won't work.
You'll have to use one of

- the "deprecated" `dnvm.sh` script and dnx/dnu commands to restore and then build each sub project.
  *Note:* that yet isn't anymore available at download, and the call to `dnvm update-self` relaces the script by a "404" ...
- The "Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host", "dotnet" (that I don't use)

It should mostly work, if you've got Dnx, try this command line, from the `src` sub-dir of the NuGet3 source code:

`(for d in *; do (cd $d && dnu restore && dnu build); done)2>&1|tee build-all.log`

For me, using Debian-8, there are build failures:

- *NuGet.CommandLine.XPlat*
- *NuGet.Configuration*, **but it succeeds for the "net451" framework**
- *NuGet.Packaging.Core*
- *NuGet.Packaging*
- *NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3*, **but it's OK @dnxcore50** (don't ask me why) ...

*YANote:* If code cannot be transformed anywhere but by M$, this is cannot be source code for me : I cannot not use it as a source. This is a secret code, a private code ... something to throw away, and that probably no one cares.